# laravel pass data from controller to jquery using json

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I want to pass data from controller to jquery using json don't know where is the problem but fro the jquery code I think its working fine as I tested the success code but can't get back the result from controller

**home.blade**

```
    <form role="form" name="form_address" id="form_address" action="" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
  <input type="text" id="postal_code" onFocus="geolocate()">
  <input type="text" id="totaldistance"  onFocus="geolocate()">
 </form>
  <button id="save_address">Save</button>
```

```js
 <script>
$("#save_address").click(function (e) {
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
         'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    }
   });

   e.preventDefault();
  var form = document.forms.namedItem("form_address");
  var formData = new FormData(form); 
  $.ajax({
     type: "get",
    url: 'Get_distance',
    contentType: false,
    data: formData, 
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
      $('#totaldistance').val(data.distance); 
    }
   });
  });
```

**web.php**

```js
Route::post('Get_distance','HomeController@getdistance');
```

**controller**

```js
public function getdistance(Request $request)
{
  $distance =$request->postal_code;

  return Response::json(array(
    'distance' => $distance,  
  ));
}
```

Comment: Did you get an error message on ajax error callback?

Comment: @JustinusHermawan  http://localhost/crisp/public/Get_distance?[object%20FormData] 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Click it from devtools and see what kind of error Laravel returns to you. And put `name="postal_code"` on your `<input type="text" id="postal_code" onFocus="geolocate()">` tag.

Comment: even if i added in controller $distance='gg'; I will not get a result and dont know how to use divtool

Comment: Change your ajax type to `"POST`", because your route type is `POST` not `GET`.

Comment: @JustinusHermawan I changed in controller to  $distance= "hhhhh";
  return response()->json([$distance]) and working fine thank u

Comment: You're welcome, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Change your ajax type to `POST`, because your route type is `POST`, not `GET`.

Comment: thank you but its not about post or get now it works with get now

Answer (score 0):

Your defined route in web.php is a POST request, but your Ajax method is set to GET request. Change web.php to a GET request for it to work. Make sure to provide an error function to catch any errors from server side.

Or vice versa, change Ajax request to POST since you already added the csrf setup.